# Installation incomplete of mysql-server-8.0 in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, software-installation, kubuntu, mysql

I'm unable to start my MySQL server on Kubuntu 20.04. I've tried many times to install and to remove the installed packages. I've followed this thread: [Can't get MYSQL8 to work on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235829/cant-get-mysql8-to-work-on-ubuntu-20-04).

Following the [suggestion of ExploitFate](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235833/618353), I've got some improvements, but when I run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-8.0
```

I have the following output:

```
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2021-05-14T20:21:24.150954Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log. Warning: Unable to start the server.
```

If I try `sudo systemctl status mysql.service` the output is:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-05-14 22:14:18 CEST; 1h 23min ago    Main PID: 47596 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Data Dictionary upgrade from MySQL 5.7 in progress"

may 14 22:14:16 hades systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server... may 14 22:14:18 hades systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE may 14 22:14:18 hades systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. may 14 22:14:18 hades systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

Here is the error log file of `mysql`:

```
2021-05-14T21:16:55.848036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2021-05-14T21:16:55.849055Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 48092
2021-05-14T21:16:55.860384Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server]
Starting upgrade of data directory.
2021-05-14T21:16:55.860441Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.255989Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.259487Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010781] [Server] Found ./mysql/index_stats.frm file in mysql schema. DD will create .ibd file with same name. Please rename table and start upgrade process again.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.259883Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010336] [Server] Found .frm file with same name as one of the Dictionary Tables.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.260611Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.261061Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-05-14T21:16:57.262020Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-05-14T21:16:58.011540Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-05-14T21:16:58.016177Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010065] [Server] Failed to shutdown components infrastructure.
```

Apparently `mysql` is present, but I didn't finish the configuration of it.

I don't have more ideas and I think I'm in a deadlock. Any ideas to help me?

Comment: I've read the log, but I don't know how I can rename the table, since I cannot access in mysql. I'm trying to uninstall the mysql server completely. I follow the steps that said me Teso. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the password.

I had the same issue and solved it yesterday, as well on a Kubuntu 20.04 and MySQL-Server 8.0.
Since you have already tried a few things, you have some errors in the system, these must be fixed first.
Now you have to uninstall the MySQL server completely.

```
su root
systemctl stop mysql.service
systemctl disable mysql.service
systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket
apt autoclean
apt clean
```

If installed, also remove **php** and **phpmyadmin**. If not skip this step.

```
apt remove --purge phpmyadmin
apt remove --purge php-*
```

Watch the uninstall log, look for warnings and error messages.

> dpkg: warning: while removing php7.4-cli, directory '/etc/php/7.4' not
> empty so not removed

```
rm -rf /etc/php/7.4
```

Continue

```
apt remove --purge mysql*
dpkg --configure -a
apt autoremove
rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/opt/mssql /usr/bin/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz
```

This command will delete the MySQL user and all associated files, therefore the disk will be completely scanned for MySQL user data and depending on the speed, size and occupancy this may take longer. Unmount all other disks.

```
deluser --remove-all-files --force mysql
```

At this point you will get an warning message.

> Removing files ...
> Removing user mysql ...
> Warning: group mysql has no more members.
> Done.

Check if the **group mysql** is removed.

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep mysql
cat /etc/group | grep mysql
```

Should be without resultet, empty.

Now reboot the system

```
reboot
```

Next reinstall the MySql-Server

```
su root
apt update --fix-missing && apt --fix-broken install && apt full-upgrade && apt autoremove
apt install php
apt install php-mysql
apt install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

Use a password with at least 8 characters, of which at least one must be an uppercase letter, one a lowercase letter, one a number and one a special character.
Not all special characters are allowed, but there is no error message if you enter a wrong character and that's the problem.
Use these: **( )** 
Example password: `H4CkM31Fy()Uc4n`

---

password validation police

[image]

Comment: Thank you Teso for your fast answer. I follow these steps and I provide you the potencial error message.

Comment: I've followed all the steps. When I've uninstalled the MySQL completely I didn't get an error. I've reinstall the MySQL-Server but it still doesn't work when I execute `mysql_secure_installation`. Here it is my output: `# mysql_secure_installation 

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: Which **password validation police** did you choose?

Comment: I didn't choose a password validation police.

Comment: You have to change the PVP manually. I'll make a new answer, this is too complicated. Can you login to mysql by CLI?

Comment: Thank you. No, I can't. Should I install mysqladmin or something similar?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Then, you can see that I cannot login to mysql by CLI.

Comment: I've followed your steps on uninstallation of mysql and php. Maybe the error that you commented is related to the message "the group 'mysql' does not exist". I had this message when I executed `deluser --group --remove-all-files --force mysql`

Comment: I've followed your steps on installation and I've solved my problem. According to `systemclt status mysql.service` MySQL is working and is active. I also login in MySQL and I changed the plugin for the root to caching_sha2_password. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I updated my system yesterday and restarted the computer, now I have the same issue and I also need to reinstall the MySQL server :-D

Answer (score 0):

I provide you a screenshot. You can see that when I execute `mysql_secure_installation` I get an error, since I cannot connect to MySQL.

[image]

If I execute `mysql -u root -p` and I type the root password the shell answer me:

> Enter password:
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL
> server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

After I rebooted the computer I cannot login to mysql, but I have this status:

> javier@hades:~$ sudo systemctl status mysql.service
> ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enable>
> Active: inactive (dead)

Then I try:

> javier@hades:~$ sudo systemctl start mysql.service
> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
> javier@hades:~$ sudo systemctl status mysql.service
> ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enable>
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-05-15 04:33:40 CEST; 16s ago
> Process: 2637 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, s>
>
> may 15 04:33:40 hades systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYW8r.png): mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter>
> may 15 04:33:40 hades systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYW8r.png): Stopped MySQL Community Server.
> may 15 04:33:40 hades systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYW8r.png): mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> may 15 04:33:40 hades systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYW8r.png): mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> may 15 04:33:40 hades systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYW8r.png): Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

I rebooted again my computer and I check if KWallet is working. I think it is working as you can see.

```
javier@hades:~$ systemctl status | grep kwalletd5
           │     ├─1808 /usr/bin/kwalletd5 --pam-login 7 3
           │     └─2554 grep --color=auto kwalletd5
```

I've also added the first lines of my status:

```
hades
  State: running
  Jobs: 0 queued
  Failed: 0 units
  Since: Sat 2021-05-15 12:42:38 CEST; 1h 5min ago
  CGroup: /
       ├─413 bpfilter_umh
       ├─user.slice 
       │ └─user-1000.slice 
       │   ├─user@1000.service 
       │   │ ├─pulseaudio.service 
       │   │ │ └─1803 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
       │   │ ├─init.scope 
       │   │ │ ├─1789 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
       │   │ │ └─1790 (sd-pam)
       │   │ ├─obex.service 
       │   │ │ └─2113 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
       │   │ └─dbus.service 
       │   │   ├─1805 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfil>
       │   │   ├─1903 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
       │   │   ├─1926 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
       │   │   ├─1935 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd
       │   │   ├─2039 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher
       │   │   └─2166 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/baloorunner
       │   └─session-6.scope 
       │     ├─1776 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth26e7f>
       │     ├─1808 /usr/bin/kwalletd5 --pam-login 7 3
       │     ├─1809 /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
       │     ├─1855 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
       │     ├─1876 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/start_kdeinit --kded +kcminit_sta>
       │     ├─1877 kdeinit5: Running...
       │     ├─1883 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher --fd=9
       │     ├─1886 kded5
```

I've uninstalled KWalletManager and installed again. I provide you the first lines of my systemctl status.

```
javier@hades:~$ systemctl status
● hades
   State: degraded
   Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 1 units
   Since: Sat 2021-05-15 12:42:38 CEST; 1h 34min ago
   CGroup: /
       ├─413 bpfilter_umh
       ├─user.slice 
       │ └─user-1000.slice 
       │   ├─user@1000.service 
       │   │ ├─pulseaudio.service 
       │   │ │ └─1803 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
       │   │ ├─init.scope 
       │   │ │ ├─1789 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
       │   │ │ └─1790 (sd-pam)
       │   │ ├─obex.service 
       │   │ │ └─2113 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
       │   │ └─dbus.service 
       │   │   ├─1805 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfil>
       │   │   ├─1903 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
       │   │   ├─1926 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
       │   │   ├─1935 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd
       │   │   ├─2039 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher
       │   │   └─2166 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/baloorunner
       │   └─session-6.scope 
       │     ├─1776 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth26e7f>
       │     ├─1808 /usr/bin/kwalletd5 --pam-login 7 3
       │     ├─1809 /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
       │     ├─1855 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/startplasma-x11
       │     ├─1876 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/start_kdeinit --kded +kcminit_sta>
       │     ├─1877 kdeinit5: Running...
       │     ├─1883 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/klauncher --fd=9
       │     ├─1886 kded5
       │     ├─1904 /usr/bin/kaccess
       │     ├─1909 /usr/bin/xsettingsd
       │     ├─1918 /usr/bin/plasma_session
       │     ├─1933 /usr/bin/ksmserver
       │     ├─1943 /usr/bin/kwin_x11 -session 10100109dae2000148598483700000013020002_1621>
       │     ├─1945 /usr/bin/baloo_file
       │     ├─1947 /usr/bin/plasmashell
       │     ├─1949 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1
       │     ├─1958 /usr/bin/xembedsniproxy
       │     ├─1961 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kdeconnectd
       │     ├─1966 /usr/bin/gmenudbusmenuproxy
       │     ├─1985 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/DiscoverNotifier
       │     ├─2037 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher --launch-immediately
       │     ├─2045 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessib>
       │     ├─2053 /usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
       │     ├─2062 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/org_kde_powerdevil
       │     ├─2133 /usr/bin/ksysguardd
       │     ├─2508 file.so [kdeinit5] file local:/run/user/1000/klauncherOupbUr.1.slave-so>
       │     ├─3167 /usr/bin/dolphin
       │     ├─3181 file.so [kdeinit5] file local:/run/user/1000/klauncherOupbUr.1.slave-so>
       │     ├─3277 /usr/bin/kate -b /home/javier/Programas/Amarok/amarok-2.9.71/amarok-2.9>
       │     ├─3293 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
       │     ├─3373 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsLe>
       │     ├─3429 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLe>
       │     ├─3463 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLe>
       │     ├─3513 /usr/bin/plasma-browser-integration-host /usr/lib/mozilla/native-messag>
       │     ├─3567 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -pr>
       │     ├─3720 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 6 -isForBrowser -prefsLe>
       │     ├─3823 /usr/bin/konsole
       │     ├─3830 /bin/bash
       │     ├─3901 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 8 -isForBrowser -prefsLe>
       │     ├─4549 systemctl status
       │     └─4550 pager
       ├─init.scope 
       │ └─1 /sbin/init splash
```

Comment: Have you rebooted the computer? - `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`  is the **unix socket**. The MySQL server must be running before you can change the password.

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted my computer after I uninstalled MySql Server completely.

Comment: Is the **avahi-daemon.service** running? - KWallerManager needs to ne installed.

Comment: Yes, avahi-daemon.service is running.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that your kwalletd version is different from the latest one, visible by the name kded5, for me it is kwalletd5. Uninstall kwalletd and install it again. ` apt remove --purge kwalletmanager `

Comment: I've uninstalled kwalletmanager and installed again. I've updated my answer providing my current systemctl status.

Comment: I am helpless.. The only thing I can recommend now is to repeat the uninstallation and installation of MySQL, as already described.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time. I try to repeat the uninstallation and installation as you described and I post my result this night.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset the root password via CLI in MySQL-Server**

Fix for error messages related to the root password.

Open a CLI and log in as root.

```
su root
```

It should now be possible to log via CLI in to MySQL without a password.

```
mysql -u root
```

Enter this syntax

```
SELECT user,host,plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';
```

> ```
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> | User | Host      | plugin                |
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> | root |     %     |      auth_socket      |
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> ```

The result should look like this.
If the root has wildcard **%** privileges, change them to **localhost**. If root is **localhost**, skip this step.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Host='localhost' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';
```

Change the plugin for the root to **caching_sha2_password**

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Plugin='caching_sha2_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

Now flush the settings.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Should look like this in the end.

```
SELECT user,host,plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';
```

> ```
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> | User | Host      | plugin                |
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> | root | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
> +------+-----------+-----------------------+
> ```

Finally restart the MySQL server.

```
systemctl stop mysql.service
systemctl disable mysql.service
systemctl enable mysql.service
systemctl start mysql.service
```

Sometimes it doesn't work and you have to restart the computer.

---

Check if the [KWalletManager](https://apps.kde.org/kwalletmanager5/) is working properly.

```
systemctl status
```

> ```
> State: degraded
>  Jobs: 0 queued    Failed: 3 units
> Since: Fri 2021-05-14 16:48:54 CEST; 19h ago    CGroup: /
>        ├─user.slice 
>        │ └─user-1000.slice 
>        │   ├─user@1000.service …
>        │   │ ├─pulseaudio.service 
>        │   │ │ └─994 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
>        │   │ ├─init.scope 
>        │   │ │ ├─988 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
>        │   │ │ └─989 (sd-pam)
>        │   │ ├─obex.service 
>        │   │ │ └─1337 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
>        │   │ └─dbus.service 
>        │   │   ├─1011 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --sys>
>        │   │   ├─1109 /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5
>        │   │   ├─1114 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
>        │   │   ├─1163 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanagerd
>        │   │   ├─1210 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kf5/kscreen_backend_launcher
>        │   │   ├─1431 /usr/bin/krunner
>        │   │   ├─1452 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/baloorunner
>        │   │   └─1560 /usr/bin/kwalletd5
> ```

```
systemctl status | grep kwalletd5
```

> ```
>        │   │   └─1560 /usr/bin/kwalletd5
>        │     └─24924 grep --color=auto kwalletd5
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get the same error.
> root@hades:/home/javier# mysql -u root
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: Uninstall phpMyAdmin and PHP ` apt remove --purge phpmyadmin php* `  then repeat the MySQL uninstall again.

Comment: I don't have phpmyadmin, this package is not installed. Also, I did not install php.

Comment: apt install php

Comment: I've installed php. Should I try to start mysql?

Comment: After I installed php I rebooted my computer  and I get the same error in mysql.

Comment: I've updated my answer providing the status of KWalletManager and also the systemctl status.