# Broken MySQL Installation, Cant Install or Uninstall

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, dpkg, mysql

So, ive installed MySQL but in the middle my PC Decided to crash and the Linux Terminal died therefore cancelling the operation... Now when i try to install it i get this

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ive tried doing some steps like

```
1st Try:
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

2nd Try:
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But still cannot get working no matter what i try, if anybody could help me or point me in the right direction would be a massive help... Ive been trying to fix this for now 2 hours and really out of ideas...

Edit:
Also, i cannot upgrade the server using `sudo apt-get upgrade` as i get the same error

```
root@hs1:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: There are some options [here](https://www.tecmint.com/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-in-ubuntu/) you can try.

Comment: Ive tried them keep getting the same errors


```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: @24601 So ive tried your solutions again still no hope... Anything you could recommend? As now the whole system cannot be updated and some services playing up, this is a development server at home but now i cannot use it sadly.. Anything else i could try as i have no clue how i can recover from this...

Comment: You are tring to install mysql-server-5.7 when have already mysql-server-8.0 installed. Try to fix with https://askubuntu.com/a/1235833/1073898

Comment: @ExploitFate Yeah ignore my mistakes there, I meant to copy my 8.0 one but as I was looking at another page I accidentally copied that, I’ve tried the stops still have the same issue and no luck..

Comment: What’s even worse is I can’t even upgrade my system now.. I’m pretty screwed I think?

Answer (score 2):

So I’ve finally got it fixed!! For anyone who is wanting to resolve this issue you need to do:

```
sudo dpkg remove mysql-server && sudo dpkg remove mysql-server-8.0
```

That has fixed the issue for me and then I reinstalled it just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm -rf ./mysql-*
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-8.0
```

It is ok!